# How to assign value read from firebase to variable

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I am trying to read the value from firebase and assign it to a global variable but it didn't work.

```
    public points: any;

    readPoints(): any{
        this.userProfile.child(this.user.uid).once('value').then((snapshot) =>{
            this.points = snapshot.val().user_points;
        });
    }
    console.log(this.points); //undefined




 Users{
          SAdS4cW57DSLuWr2obbZYUHsmAL2{
                user_points: 20
.....
```

Comment: can you update you question with a exemple of you database structure?

Comment: i added the db structure

Answer (score 2):

Well, your variable is `this.points` but you are trying to print `this.point`

Comment: this is  not a problem! i just typed here wrongly cuz I didn't copy from code!

Answer (score 1):

I read this [article](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/keeping-our-promises-and-callbacks_76.html) from firebase and seem like solution is to call another function instead of assign value directly to variable

```
public points: any;

readPoints(): any{
    this.userProfile.child(this.user.uid).once('value').then((snapshot) =>{
         this.getPoints(snapshot.val().user_points);
    });

}
getPoints(point: any = null): any{
    this.points = parseInt(point) + 20;
    console.log("point="+ this.points);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems right to me, try printing your `snapshot.val()` to see what it gives you. I'll just add a code of how i imagine your full database query is.

```
firebase.database().ref('Users/').child(this.user.uid).once('value').then(snapshot => {
  this.points = snapshot.val().user_points;
})
```

Does it gives any error on the console? Is it getting the `this.user.id` right?